# Запись числа -128 в Java в двоичном представлении

Tags: java, binary, арифметика, cast

Есть код:

```
public class Main{
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        byte a;
        a = (byte)0b1000_0000;
        System.out.println(a + ":\t0b1000_0000");

    }
}
```

В коде я привожу число -128 к типу `byte`, так как это литерал типа `int`. Объясните, почему ( без приведения типа работать не будет ).
Разве код не должен работать и без приведения, так как диапазон типа `byte` [-128/127].

Есть код:

```
public class Main{
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        byte a;
        a = 0b1000_0000;
        System.out.println(a + ":\t0b1000_0000");

    }
}
```

Ожидал что работать будет так.

Comment: Компилятор хочет убедиться, что вы понимаете, что делаете. Может вы хотели 128 получить, а не -127.

Comment: `0b1000_0000` - константа типа `int` со значением *128*. Вы пытаетесь поместить это значение в переменную типа `byte`, которая такое значение содержать не может. Приведение говорит компилятору что вы готовы пойти на изменение значения, чтобы оно поместилось в байт.

Comment: @StanislavVolodarskiy получается вcе константы по умолчанию являются int ?

Comment: Да, [3.10.1. Integer Literals](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se22/html/jls-3.html#jls-3.10.1).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Бинарная константа положительная и, очевидно, в байт не влезает.